# Passing state to children in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a section component where I have:

```
state = {
  text: '',
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
        <SpecialTextBox text={this.state.text}></SpecialTextBox>
    </div>
}
```

I'm able to access this.state.text in the child component (SpecialTextBox) where I can access it, but changing it doesn't seem to update the value in the parent.

I'm doing setState on key press for the child which updates this.state for the child but not the parent.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Let me guess - You are passing a primitive value, and so its a copy ? Then when you update it - of course nothing happens on the original.

Comment: Have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html .

Comment: @c69 I'm very curious now. Can you clarify what you mean? If you use `this.setState` to change `this.state.text`, a string, why would that not update the `SpecialTextBox`'s `this.props.text`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as per the React docs,

> State is similar to props, but it is private and fully controlled by the component.

So your child component state is updated but not the state of the parent. If you want to update the state of the parent you can

1. Lift the state to the Parent component and pass prop functions to your child component which will update the state in the parent component and also the state of the child component since it will be receiving the parent state as props.

> See here [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)